# how to append child divs to parent divs equally with using same class in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a following html

```
    <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
    <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
    <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
    <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
    <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
    <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
```

initially all parent divs has one child div. I am trying to append new child divs to parents equally.For example if 1,2,3 parent div has 2 child and the others have only one, i should append new child to 4. parent div. Is there any short way in jquery to do this without looping all of parants and testing the number of divs they have ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You will always have to loop through "parent" elements and check the amount of children it has to perform or not an action on them.

Comment: yes i am looping all parents and what i am triyng to do is not simple in the question so i am looking for whether there is a simple way for doing this or not

Comment: show your code so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function `_.minBy` from beautiful [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#minBy)

```
var minDiv = _.minBy($('div.parent'), function(item) {
    return $(item).find('div.child').length;
  });

  $(minDiv).append('<div class="child"></div>');
```

See the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huwjmgLy/) and thank the contributors of this awesome library.

Comment: thanks for your response it is very fast solution for my problem. i dont know what the lodash is before your response.Thanks again